# Solving $A^TAx=A^Tb$ without using $A^TA$ or its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 2&3\\ -2&1}$ and $b=\pmatrix{1\\ 1\\ 1}$, solve $A^TAx = A^Tb$ without calculating $A^TA$ or its inverse.

I solved a previous problem in this set where I calculated the QR factorization of $A$ using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. I used Kahn Academy's approach and found $u_1$ and $u_2$ for $A$ (orthonormal bases?).

In order not to calculate $A^TA$ or its inverse, I have from the properties of orthogonal bases and Gram-Schmidt that if $Q$ has orthonormal columns and $Q$ is $m\times n$ where $m\ne n$ then:
\begin{align*}
Qx &= b ,\\
Q^TQx &= Q^Tb,\\
x &= Q^Tb.
\end{align*}
My $Q=(u_1, u_2)$, therefore, can I perform $Q^Tb$ and get my $x$?  (Seems almost too simple) As always, any help is greatly appreciated.  :)

Comment: Please, correct your question according to Latex/MathJax format.

Comment: I found this difficult to follow. You can learn how to format math on this website [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Kaster and Daryl~  Sorry!  I will try to use Latex/MathJax formatting in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you substitute in $QR$ for $A$ on the lefthand side, you get
\begin{align}
(QR)^TQRx&=A^Tb \\
R^TRx=A^Tb
\end{align}

This is not so bad to solve - just compute $y:=A^Tb$, then backsolve twice to find $x$ in $R^TRx=y$. The steps are:

1. $y=A^Tb$. Matrix-vector multiply to get intermediary result $y$.
2. $R^Tz=y$. Triangular backsolve to get intermediary result $z$.
3. $Rx=z$. Triangular backsolve to get $x$.

Comment: ~  So my idea won't work?  I have seen the back substitution procedure.  However, the prof stated for Q mxn where m=n, Q is square and orthogonal...leads to Rx=Q^Tb.  So I didn't think that this was useful for my problem.  That's why I chose the other procedure.  I will try what you suggested.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: Ok, so suppose that $x=Q^Tb$. Then since $Q$ is orthogonal, applying it to $b$ can only make it smaller. Ie, $||x|| \le ||b||$. This can't always work since there could be an $A$ with very very small entries (eg, .001*identity), and then to solve $A^TAx=A^Tb$, $x$ would need to have very large entries to compensate.

Comment: ~ Yep, math wizard!  Nothing like that even crosses my mind.  Amazing!  Makes sense. I did do it that way for my Q and b and x =[sqrt(3)/3,sqrt(2)]. (I'm using Matlab so that's why the notation)  I am working your suggestion at the moment.  Let's see what happens...  Thanks again!

Comment: ~  If all my calculations are correct, x = [1/12, 1/2].